# Pixeldriver P9813 with HP LED driver AL8860WT - transistor/Mosfet needed?

Tags: led-driver, led-strip, ws2812b, pixels

Refering to my [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/674001/hp-led-driver-rgbw-w-al8860wt-7-not-working-all-channels-are-constantly-on), I want to drive a bunch of High power LED drivers ([Datashsheet AL8860WT-7](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1119996/DIODES/AL8860WT-7.html)) With a Pixel-IC ([Datashsheet P9813](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeeedDocument/Grove-Chainable_RGB_LED/master/res/P9813_datasheet.pdf)).

This is my concept:
[image]

My project so far: connecting the R, G or B Pin of the Pixel-IC directly to the driver does not work, as these pins seem to need some kind of a Pullup or other things which I simply don't know. This is the from the P9813 Datasheet:
[image]
The resistor RB seem to work like a Pullup in this case, but I can't figure out, how this would work with the AL8860 Driver. This Driver needs a PWM signal > 2.5V to switch the load with full current.
When I connect the P9813 with the pullup-resistor (RB=2.2k) shown above, I get a constant voltage of about 1V at the drivers' input with a ripple of about 0.1V.
This is the circuit so far:
[image]

I would be very happy to figure out:

- Do I have to use a transistor to switch the driver?
- if no: What do I have to change?
- if yes: would I rather use a bipolar transistor or a mosfet? these cheap levelshifting modules for example often use BSS138 mosfets for I2C stuff etc...
  Unfortunately I have these only in a SOT-23 package laying arround and its a pain to get these tiny chips working on a breadboard.

Your advice will be highly appreciated!

edit:
I have successfully used a Bipolar transistor to get the driver to work with the P9813, but with a inverted signal. So I thought I'll use two transistors to invert the signal twice.

This is my latest schematic:
[image]
Would this work ?

Comment: So in your previous question the problem was that the "MCU" was actually a constant current LED driver? And your goal is to take the 10 or 20 mA drive current and turn that into a 0-2.5v control signal for a second LED driver? Is that right

Comment: No, in my previous question the mcu was given a pwm signal to the driver. Now it's a Pixel-IC that is producing the pwm signal (4500hz btw) for the driver.

Comment: Can you show an actual circuit diagram of the connections?  The constant current outputs on your driver just pull current to ground, they don't produce a voltage, so you need to provide a voltage source (the pull up to VCC).  Voltage should be VCC-current * resistance.

Comment: schematic has been added :)